# "The chosen operation is not enabled" when I try to put breakpoint in IBM Intergration Toolkit

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

There is the code:

```
    CREATE FIELD OutputRoot.JSON.Data.params.dataFiles IDENTITY(JSON.Array)dataFiles;
    DECLARE fileref REFERENCE TO InputLocalEnvironment.Variables.FilesContents.Item[1];
    DECLARE nameref REFERENCE TO InputLocalEnvironment.OutputXML.XMLNSC.*:Test.*:RefInfo[1];        
    WHILE (LASTMOVE(fileref)=TRUE OR LASTMOVE(nameref)=TRUE) DO
        CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.JSON.Data.params.dataFiles TYPE NameValue NAME 'content' VALUE fileref;
        CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.JSON.Data.params.dataFiles TYPE NameValue NAME 'fileName' VALUE nameref.*:RefType;                                           
        MOVE fileref NEXTSIBLING;
        MOVE nameref NEXTSIBLING;
    END WHILE;
```

I want to put breakpoints at 8 and 9 lines (CREATE LASTCHILD...), but I get a information message "The chosen is not enabled.". But I can put breakpoint on 10 and 11 lines (MOVE). For example, while debugging, I can not reach breakpoints at MOVE statements and statements following WHILE loop, because debug freezes. When I disable debug, flow works until the end.

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only one to experience pain with the debugger.

My workaround is to run a user trace using mqsichangetrace https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/an28100_.htm followed by mqsireadlog and mqsiformatlog.

```
Start --> mqsichangetrace IB9NODE -u -e default -l debug -r
Stop  --> mqsichangetrace IB9NODE -u -e default -l none
```